# How to make an Asus G75 laptop more energy savvy

Tags: laptop, power-management, asus

I just bought an Asus G75 and the battery is lasting less than 2 hours, even when doing nothing. I read somewhere that energy saving is not efficient on linux, at least by default. Is there something I can do to improve this ? Thanks

Comment: what is the battery backup of windows? Please post output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 0):

When on battery, I set Jupiter ('http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html') to 'Power saving'. This significantly increases your autonomy.